# How to calculate new height width of canvas after scaling?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on HTML5 project and i am getting somne problem.

Actually i have a canvas on which i am drawing image by using

```
ctx1.scale(0.5,0.5); // let assume
ctx1.drawImage(Image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

I want to calculate new height width of image after scaling (i.e scale=0.5). So that i could change the canvas height and width fit to image (as boundary).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Its just as simple as multiplying the width by the scale!
not sure about syntax though!
canvas.width * scale

Answer (score 0):

It is just as simple as multiplying the width by the scale!

Not sure about syntax though:

```
canvas.width * scale
```